# "My class ended earlier than expected" vs. "my class ended quicker than expected"

Tags: grammar

I'm studying English at the moment and I don't know which one of these is correct:

> My class ended **earlier** than expected.
>
> My class ended **quicker** than expected.

Could I also say *my class ended so quickly*?

Answer (score 1):

They mean slightly different things.

- Saying *My class ended **earlier** than expected* means it ended before some assumed clock time.  e.g., the class was scheduled to end at 4:00 but the professor let everyone go at 3:50.
- *My class ended **quicker** than expected* means the time from the beginning to the end (total class time, aka *duration*) was shorter than expected.  e.g., the class was supposed to be an hour long but was only fifty minutes long.

Comment: Another interpretation for "quicker" could mean how time during class was perceived. Class A and Class B can have the same duration, but Class A can go quicker than Class B.

Answer (score 0):

**Quicker than** doesn't sound as natural here as **earlier than** or **sooner than**. The meaning of

```
My class went quicker than expected.
```

is similar although it may also suggest that while the duration was as expected, it was more interesting and seemed to go by faster. Cf. Einstein: “Put your hand on a hot stove for a minute, and it seems like an hour. Sit with a pretty girl for an hour, and it seems like a minute. That's relativity.”